# Google maps Adding infowindow on click from geojson file

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm looking to add info windows on click of markers on a map.  I have used the example code (below) from google to create the marker map from geojson files dragged and dropped in the window.  I would like the info windows to draw their text from the same geojson file.  I have tried various example codes to generate this but I can't get it to work (I have zero background in programming).  Is it possible to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Drag and Drop GeoJSON</title>
    <style>
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
      #map { height: 100% }
      #drop-container {
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
      }
      #drop-silhouette {
        color: white;
        border: white dashed 8px;
        height: calc(100% - 56px);
        width: calc(100% - 56px);
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZiS0dEAGQAZABkkPCsTwAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB90LHAIvICWdsKwAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAACdklEQVR42u3csU7icBzA8Xp3GBMSeRITH8JHMY7cRMvmVmXoE9TAcJubhjD4ApoiopgqDMWAKAgIcSAiCfxuwhwROVJbkPD9rP23ob8vpZCQKgoAAAAAAAAAAPDYyiK/eNM05bNtr6+vSjgcXiHxDMkE1WpVFvGcfpCVICAIQUAQgoAgBAFBCAKCgCAEAUEIAoIQBAQhCAgCghAEBCEICEIQEIQgIAgIQhAQhCAgCEFAEIKAICAIQUAQgoAgBAFBCDIzhmFINBo9/K6D0XVddnd3ZaneDY7jSCqVcn3SfjyeKRKJbJ2dnYllWbKUl2i5XJaXlxdJJBIy7yDHx8fy9vYm6XR6OWMM3d/fi4hIqVSSWCwmsw5ycHAgrVZLRETOz8+XO8ZQpVJ5H2Y6nRZN0/b9DqLruhSLxfd9MpkMMT6L0uv1JJlMih9BhveJwWDwvv7i4oIY4zw8PIwMtt1uSzweF6+CHB0dSbfbHVmbzWaJMcnj4+OHAd/d3cne3p64DWKapjw/P39Yd3l5SYxpVKvVsYO2LEtUVd2ZNoiu6+I4ztg1V1dXxPAiSq/Xk5OTk0k9pNVqyenp6ch94l+5XI4YbtRqNfHa9fX1t43xcwGa/Nnc3PwdDAY9OZht28rGxgZPvP6KSCSy9fT09OUrw7ZtPqa8jFKv113HuLm5IYbXVFXdcRPl9vaWGH5GaTQaU8fI5/PE8JumafvNZvO/MQqFAjFmJRqNHk6Ksqgx5vr1zzAM2d7edr3/6uqqsra2NnZbp9NR+v2+62OHQqG5zObXPIMEAgFlfX3dl2N79btl1viTA0FAEIKAIAQBAAAAAAAAsMz+Ai1bUgo6ebm8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="drop-container"><div id="drop-silhouette"></div></div>
    <script>
      /* Map functions */

      var map;

      function initMap() {
        // set up the map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.240479, -0.902656),
          zoom: 12
        });
        }


      function loadGeoJsonString(geoString) {
        var geojson = JSON.parse(geoString);
        map.data.addGeoJson(geojson);
        zoom(map);
      }

      /**
       * Update a map's viewport to fit each geometry in a dataset
       * @param {google.maps.Map} map The map to adjust
       */
      function zoom(map) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
          processPoints(feature.getGeometry(), bounds.extend, bounds);
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }

      /**
       * Process each point in a Geometry, regardless of how deep the points may lie.
       * @param {google.maps.Data.Geometry} geometry The structure to process
       * @param {function(google.maps.LatLng)} callback A function to call on each
       *     LatLng point encountered (e.g. Array.push)
       * @param {Object} thisArg The value of 'this' as provided to 'callback' (e.g.
       *     myArray)
       */
      function processPoints(geometry, callback, thisArg) {
        if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
          callback.call(thisArg, geometry);
        } else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
          callback.call(thisArg, geometry.get());
        } else {
          geometry.getArray().forEach(function(g) {
            processPoints(g, callback, thisArg);
          });
        }
      }


      /* DOM (drag/drop) functions */

      function initEvents() {
        // set up the drag & drop events
        var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map');
        var dropContainer = document.getElementById('drop-container');

        // map-specific events
        mapContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', showPanel, false);

        // overlay specific events (since it only appears once drag starts)
        dropContainer.addEventListener('dragover', showPanel, false);
        dropContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        dropContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', hidePanel, false);
      }

      function showPanel(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('drop-container').style.display = 'block';
        return false;
      }

      function hidePanel(e) {
        document.getElementById('drop-container').style.display = 'none';
      }

      function handleDrop(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        hidePanel(e);

        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        if (files.length) {
          // process file(s) being dropped
          // grab the file data from each file
          for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
              loadGeoJsonString(e.target.result);
            };
            reader.onerror = function(e) {
              console.error('reading failed');
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
          }
        } else {
          // process non-file (e.g. text or html) content being dropped
          // grab the plain text version of the data
          var plainText = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
          if (plainText) {
            loadGeoJsonString(plainText);
          }
        }

        // prevent drag event from bubbling further
        return false;
      }

      function initialize() {
        initMap();
        initEvents();
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MYKEY]=initialize"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of the GeoJson:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Dayofyear": "365" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -0.68707977611089, 52.185136516710998 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Dayofyear": "365" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -0.859024422605226, 52.390033187765177 ] } }
]
}
```

[image]

For example:  I would like to be able to have a pop up on click of the marker with the infowindow displaying the "Dayofyear" data from the GeoJson for that marker.

Comment: Where is the GeoJSON?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The code above creates a window into which a geojson file can be dropped.  At the moment I am using geojson files stored on my desktop.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (or provide  sample GeoJSON in the question)

Answer (score 0):

To add infowindow on a marker, as you asked, you can try the simple code provided by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).

Basically, you need to add an infowindow object and open it inside your map in your function processPoints():

```
function processPoints(geometry, callback, thisArg) {

    if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
      callback.call(thisArg, geometry);

    } else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
        callback.call(thisArg, geometry.get());
        var contentString = "yourTextHere";
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            position: geometry.get()
        });
        infowindow.open(map);

    } else {
      geometry.getArray().forEach(function(g) {
        processPoints(g, callback, thisArg);
      });
    }
  }
```

If you need additional information/options on infowindow, you can check Google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#open).